# xmlwrite X number of csv rows

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am writing an xml doc from a csv list the csv list is 1 column of 300 rows and I want to write only 24 rows but it keeps writing the whole column. I

```
Carton = Root+ '/SNS/Cartons.csv'
EA = csv.reader(open(Carton))
def Twntyfour():
    earow = 0        
    for erow in EA:
        if earow == 0:
            tags = erow
            for i in range(len(tags)):
                xmlData.write('          <cmn:SerialNumber>'+erow[i]+'<cmn:SerialNumber>'+"\n")
                earow += 24
Twntyfour()
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to limit rows, so what does "keeps writing the whole column" mean? It keeps writing rows you don't want? What is EA? A list or perhaps a csv file iterator?

Comment: You take the number of items of the first row and use that as the column count of all additional rows. Is that the thing you want limited to 24?

Comment: My csv file is 1 column of 300 I want to write 24 rows of it at different places in my xml my example above writes everything

Comment: `for erow in EA` --> for each line in the csv file. Your code loop over every line.Add a counter and increment it every time you are in the loop. When the counter value is 24 - break

Comment: I added a counter but I don't think its right now my output is only 1 row. my edit is reflected in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` to grab 24 rows from the csv reader at a time.

```
import itertools

Carton = Root+ '/SNS/Cartons.csv'
EA = csv.reader(open(Carton))
def Twntyfour():
    for row in itertools.islice(EA, 0, 24):
        xmlData.write('          <cmn:SerialNumber>'
                + row[0]
                + '<cmn:SerialNumber>'+"\n")
Twntyfour()
```

Comment: This worked beautifully on its own but when i added it to my code it wouldn't write out any lines since this was now near the bottom of my script and it had already reached the end of the CSV file i need to get back to the first row prior to executing this  definition. I tried EA.seek(0) but it returned an error:AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'seek'